# "haven't" vs "have no" vs "does/do not have"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Are there differences in meaning ? When we say:

- I have no *____*
- I don't have *____*
- I haven't *____*
- I haven't got [a/an] *____*

EDIT: Replaced the placeholder *something* to ______.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about "I have no ____" - for example, ["I have no doubt".](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+have+no+doubt%22&oq=%22I+have+no+doubt%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3741j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22I+have+no+doubt%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099)

Comment: @Cardinal - I'm not sure I understand your question.  Consider this exchange: "Hi, I'd like to buy some apples and cherries." - "I can sell you apples, but *I have no cherries.*"  That's a perfectly normal, unremarkable use for "I have no ___" or "I don't have ____" that's very different from "I have nothing".

Answer (score 1):

There are no real differences in meaning between any of them in a general sense, but they are not necessarily interchangeable. The right form/s to use can vary depending on the subject you insert.

Answer (score -3):

If you use " not" in any verb you have to use the prefix Any..
I don't have anything 
I have something
I haven't gotten (got) anything

' I haven't something' is incorrect,  'I haven't gotten anything ' is correct

You should look up the perfect present tense, it's really not that difficult :)

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Unfortunately, I really have to disagree with your answer.  You don't have to use "any" when you use "not"; "I haven't a ___ " is perfectly acceptable at least in British English; and "I haven't gotten ___" means something different from "I haven't _____".

Comment: This is a truly horrible answer. It is true that "have some" is frequently negated by "do not have any." It is not true that this is an invariable rule in American English. "I don't have Sanskrit dictionaries in my library" is a perfectly idiomatic and grammatical sentence. Furthermore, if I said, as is equally idiomatic and grammatical, "I don't have any Sanskrit dictionaries in my library," "any" is not a prefix. Of the four options asked about, only one is in a perfect tense so the issue has nothing to with the perfect aspect of a verb.